# Caveats about compressed DMG?

Tags: macos, archiving, dmg-image

I was curious about using compressed and modifiable DMGs to store all kinds of data.

Eg: I've got a tablatures set for guitar which is like 120mb zipped and contains 60-70k files and 1.3Gb unzipped. Instead that keeping them unzipped I could store them inside a DMG to be able to access them without worrying about extracting (since the operation it is invisible compared to using a plain archive like a zip) and without cluttering the file system with lots of entries. Another example could be my abandonware collection, a lot of files, a lot of folders but not any really need to keep them directly inside the file system.

What I was wondering about is:

- is it possible to have a DMG that is either compressed either modifiable? (Adding files to it just by drag'n'drop')
- will this create any severe performance issue when accessing that files?
- is it in general a good/usable idea?
- finally, are there other more "cross-platform" solutions? Since DMGs are natively available only on OSX (I think)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DMG files are simply ISOs.  The Disk Utility can create them in various formats (disc ready, encrypted, etc.) but if you select a compressed option the image will not be modifiable.  They are completely portable as long as it's a format that system can read.

I've been using an encrypted DMG since I switched to OSX many years ago and have had no issues with them performance-wise.

Comment: Why then usually downloaded DMGs are smaller than its extracted content?

Comment: It could have something to do with the filesystems involved, but that's a good question.  It would be nice to know for sure. In regards to compressed DMGS, they don't have built-in compression like zips or anything.

Comment: Actually if I create a sparse image with diskutil and then I select it and convert it through the convert button it allows me to choose as image format "compressed" so maybe it is possible to compress DMGs but without having a modifiable one.

Comment: Just tried: it creates it and compress it but then it's not modifiable anymore :(

Comment: @Jack ... indicating those features (modifyable & compressed) are exclusive.

Comment: Yes, it seems so!

Comment: @kweerious DMGs can be compressed, but then they aren't modifiable. There is an option in Disk Utility to create a compressed image.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to have a DMG that is either compressed either modifiable? (Adding files to it just by drag'n'drop')

Yes. OS X can by using the somewhat more advanced bZip2 format.  If you don't get the option in the Disk Utility format options try the open-source [dmgCreator](http://dmgcreator.sourceforge.net/en/).

> will this create any severe performance issue when accessing that files

That depends on your definition of "severe" -which only you can answer by trial and error.  You might try to look into a file system that includes compression natively.  The reduction in read/writes offsets the decompression time, but I don't know how well balanced the trade-off is.

> is it in general a good/usable idea?

No, disk space is cheap and big media files typically don't benefit all that much.  A text file can easily be 1/4 of the normal space, but movies, audio, and images are already compressed.

> finally, are there other more "cross-platform" solutions? Since DMGs are natively 
>   available only on OSX (I think)

Zip files are about as close to universal compression as you can get.